# PayPal Send Invoice does not send email

Tags: api, paypal, invoice

I have used CreateandSendInvoice API to send invoice in Paypal Sandbox. I have also included payer Email ID. Invoice is created in Paypal Sandbox account.But the payer does not receive an email about the Invoice in his email. I have tried different email, but still i havent get any email in his Inbox.Please anyone help me on this. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox does not send actual emails.  Instead, you would login to http://developer.paypal.com, click into your sandbox accounts, and then click the Notifications link.  Within that you'll see all of the emails you would typically see at the real email address for the account.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks. But whether live paypal will send actual invoice emails to the payer's inbox ?

Comment: Yes, the live PayPal server will send actual emails to the invoice receiver.

Comment: Hi Andrew...This is very helpful..Also In Sandbox Paypal website, Request Payment functionality is there (Not Create Invoice) with which we can request money to any payer using email address. This doesnot require an invoice. But the same functionality is not present in API. Please help me on this. Thank You

Comment: Any anyone finding this comment in the future, "request money" isn't an API option.  You have to use invoicing.